# Adding custom actions to rules

Tags: 7, users

I am trying to add custom actions, events and conditions to work with Rules interface. I began by adding custom actions by creating a custom module. Here's my code till now.

**rules_example.info :**

```
name = Rules Example
description = Test module to add new actions, events, and conditions
core = 7.x
```

**rules_example.module :**

```
<?php
/**
 */
```

**rules_example.rules.inc :**

```
<?php

 /**
  * @file
  * Example rules module to create actions, events, and conditions
  */

/**
 * Implement hook_rules_action_info()

 * Declare any meta data about actions for Rules
 */

function rules_example_rules_action_info() {
$actions = array(
    'rules_example_actions_hello_world' => array(
        'label' => t('Print Hello World on the page'),
        'group' => t('Rules Example'),
        ),
    'rules_example_actions_hello_user' => array(
        'label' => t('Print Hello to the logged in user'),
        'group' => t('Rules Example'),
        'parameter' => array(
            'account' => array(
                'type' => 'user',
                'label' => t('User to say hello to'),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    );

return $actions;
}

/**
 * The action function for rules_example_action_hello_world
 */

function rules_example_action_hello_world() {
drupal_set_message(t('Hello World'));
} 

/** 
 * The action function for rules_example_action_hello_user
 */

function rules_example_action_hello_user($account) {
drupal_set_message(t('Hello @username',
 array('@username' => $account->name)));
}
```

Well, this is it. I have saved all these files in a folder rules_example in sites/all/modules. When i install the module or rather try to install it i get this error:

**`ReflectionException: Function rules_example_actions_hello_world() does not exist in ReflectionFunction->__construct() (line 1691 of /opt/lampp/htdocs/sites/all/modules/rules/includes/rules.core.inc)`**

I am not sure what the error is. I am going to rules.core.inc but am not able to understand what is causing the error. Thanks.

Comment: shouldn't you have files[] = my_module.rules.inc in your info file?

Comment: @loolooyyyy I don't think files[] is for generally including code - it's for classes and interfaces specifically.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a typo in your code - the function name is "rules_example_actions_hello_world" in your actions definition, while the actual function is called "rules_example_action_hello_world".

Answer (score 1):

In rules_example.module, add this:

`module_load_include('inc', 'rules_example', 'rules_example.rules');`