# add action to a rule programmatically

Tags: rules

I want to add my custom action to defined rule('`commerce_checkout_new_account`'), I have found [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/59975/adding-custom-actions-to-rules). How can create my action, but I don't know how can I add it to defined rule by another module ('`commerce_checkout_new_account`').

Anybody know how can I add my custom rule action  to exists rule programmatically?

**update**

for more details: I want create my custom rule action, then add my actions to exists rule (the rule that created before by another version on in UI, I just want add my custom action to it porgrammatically )

Comment: The link which shared is covering almost what you need to achieve. Have tried implementing it? If so what are all the problems you are facing?

Comment: @Mathankumar It only create a action(and new rule) ,I want create my action then **add it to exist rules actions**

Comment: You mean to create a new action and then modify the existing rule to have this action instead of existing one??? If I'm wrong could you please explain it in detail?

Comment: @Mathankumar I want first create a action then add my action too exist rule